# Javadocs on android studio cant resolve packages used by android source

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, javadoc

I want to generate a technical documentation using java docs but there seems to be a problem. Although the classpaths are already referenced correctly

```
-classpath
"C:/Users/ASTI/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/sources/android-30;...more classpaths"
```

Java docs cant resolve the packages inside android 30 source file

```
C:\Users\ASTI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-30\java\lang\Enum.java:37: error: package libcore.util does not exist
import libcore.util.BasicLruCache;
```

Or is there a way to just ignore the subpackes on the Enum.java